# Single Ram Upgrade to Dual Ram

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, desktop

I'm wondering how easy it is to upgrade RAM I currently have 8gb single ram card. And I'd like to add another 8gb so I could get Dual Channel Mode.

I'm running Linux. Is it as easy as just inserting the ram and turning on my computer or do I need to do something in software?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering how easy it is to upgrade RAM

If the new ram is correct, when you re-start, your motherboard bios should immediately recognize the change.  You shouldn't have to do much of anything.

> I currently have 8gb single ram card. And I'd like to add another 8gb so I could get Dual Channel Mode.

You will need for both sticks of ram to exactly match.

Comment: so the operating system (ubuntu) will also recognize this automatically?

Comment: Yes, assuming the hardware is compatible with your motherboard Ubuntu (and pretty much any OS) will recognise it automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Installing more RAM is as simple as just plugging it to the motherboard and powering on the computer. You don't adjust anything from the operating system. The most you may be required to do is to enter the BIOS/UEFI and configure clock speed and timings.

Ideally you have to check your current RAM specs (clock speed and latency timings) and buy another stick with the same specifications. It's often preferable to get an identical stick (same vendor, same exact model) but in practice that's not required.

Also, the memory chips don't have to be necessarily the same size. Modern ASUS motherboards have this to say in the manual (but check your motherboard first):

> You may install varying memory sizes in Channel A and Channel B. The
>   system maps  the total size of the lower-sized channel for the
>   dual-channel configuration.  Any excess  memory from the higher-sized
>   channel is then mapped for single-channel operation

Also it *is* possible to setup dual-channel with different clock speeds with most motherboards I've seen. But this causes all of the memory to run at the speed of the slower one. And it may introduce stability issues.

The ASUS manual also says:

> Always install DIMMs with the same CAS latency. For optimum
>   compatibility, we  recommend that you obtain memory modules from the
>   same vendor.

To read more about RAM timings, read here: [Calculate performance of RAM using timing and speed](https://superuser.com/q/593772/358758). Additionally, see [Is it safe to use RAM sticks with different frequencies?](https://superuser.com/q/52340/358758).