# Will Different RAM Modules crash my system? Based on previous Answer

Tags: memory, crash

Please help me understand if this is going to be a problem. This is related to another post that was answered previously. I had tried to upgrade my system for heavy load of rendering, and there was a problem when I received the new RAM.

Previously answered in : [Is it safe to use RAM sticks with different frequencies?](https://superuser.com/questions/52340/is-it-safe-to-use-ram-sticks-with-different-frequencies)

My question is after the screenshots attached below:

[2 Different modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1V5D.png)

My Question:

Amazon shipped me a DDR4-2666 RAM module instead of a 2400 Frequency, which my system was originally shipped with. So, as per the previous answer, the superuser(‘nik’) mentioned, “2. The modules will not be acceptable by your board together and it will declare memory failure.”

So if I keep a huge file for rendering which may take about 36 to 48hrs, will this crash my system in midway? Should I even be concerned about it happening? Or is it going to be just fine if I continue with it?

Comment: Hard to answer authoritatively, it strongly depends on the hardware.

Comment: I just want to know if it will be a mistake to ignore this difference, even though there so many posts that mention its ok .. but that statement made me worry as this rendering is highly important.. (For info, my system has MS-16J9, and its MSI.)

Comment: If the rendering is absolutely that supremely critical then your only option is to take one of the sticks out and guarantee that it happens without error. Of course there is nothing to say that a stray cosmic ray won't hit your machine and cause a fatal crash in that timeframe either... If your system seems reliable as is then it is most likely fine, crashes and errors for incompatible RAM would most likely have happened within the first couple of hours if anything were truly wrong. The only way to know now is to try it. Or don't and just play it safe.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The highly rated answer seems to indicate that your system will be stable (although see a slight performance hit due to the memory channel mode) or be unstable resulting in an error pointing to the memory that has been installed.  If your system is stable then you will not recieve an error.  **It is impossible for to determine if your system will crash.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to use RAM sticks with different frequencies?](https://superuser.com/questions/52340/is-it-safe-to-use-ram-sticks-with-different-frequencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it **safe** to use RAM with 2 different frequencies

YES, the higher clock speed DIMM will **underclock** itself **if possible** to that of the lowest speed DIMM.  If the motherboard POST's (power on self test) and gets to the BIOS screen, then the RAM DIMM combination your using is valid and *safe*.  It would come down to DIMM's meeting JEDEC standards... and if different DIMM's meet a given standard then that's what matters.

for example a DDR4-3200 underclocking or downclocking itself to DDR4-2933 does not make it or any other DIMM less safe or more prone to error.  If anything downclocking would make things more stable... it's when u overclock that things overheat and become more unstable.

all the ram dimm's on your mobo must run at the same voltage, speed and timings.

> So if I keep a huge file for rendering which may take about 36 to 48hrs, will this crash my system in midway?

no

> Should I even be concerned about it happening?

no

> Or is it going to be just fine if I continue with it?

yes

sacrificing speed for reliablility you would want a highest speed rated ram (which has passed the quality control to run at those highest speeds i.e. ddr4-3200) and then manually downclock it to the lowest compatible setting via XMP (the opposite of what overclockers do)

Comment: Thanks a ton Ron! It helps clear many apprehensions...